# Fastest Pairwise Difference of Rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have an n by 3 numpy array, with each row representing a vector in 3D space.

I'd like to have a 3D n by n by 3 array with the vector at [i, j] representing the differences between each component of vectors i and j.

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 3))
>>> x
array([[4, 0, 8],
       [8, 5, 3],
       [4, 1, 6],
       [2, 2, 4]])
>>> x[:, np.newaxis] - x
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [-4, -5,  5],
        [ 0, -1,  2],
        [ 2, -2,  4]],

       [[ 4,  5, -5],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 4,  4, -3],
        [ 6,  3, -1]],

       [[ 0,  1, -2],
        [-4, -4,  3],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 2, -1,  2]],

       [[-2,  2, -4],
        [-6, -3,  1],
        [-2,  1, -2],
        [ 0,  0,  0]]])
```

This works, but is the slowest line in my program by far...slower even than my Euclidean distance code (which takes advantage of dot products and `einsum`...)

Are there any clever matrix math methods for doing what I want in a more efficient way?

Comment: Similar to this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104893/put-pairwise-differences-of-matrix-rows-in-3-d-array) from more than a year ago.

Comment: What is a typical value for `n`?

Comment: I don't see why this should be particularly slow, other than the fact the result ing nxnx3 array could be large and stretch the memory capacity of your machine.  It will have to perform n*n*3 subtractions, but it should be doing those in C code.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser A typical n in my use case is about 500.

Comment: @hpaulj Perhaps it's not absolutely slow, but it is relatively slow compared to everything else I'm doing. Maybe I'm just overreacting...